# Inkscape : How to ' crop ' something before 'saving' it?

Tags: graphics, svg, gimp, inkscape

If i open a new Inkscape document
and type

```
 TEST
```

and then try to save it ( as .svg )

the whole page is saved.

what i want is a tiny icon that reads '`TEST`'.

with no empty places around it.

sort of like "cropped" edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can

```
    File -> Document Properties or Shift+Ctrl+D
```

then

```
resize page to content
```

and click

```
resize page to drawing or selection
```

Now when you save it, it should have the desired dimensions.

Cheers